# match pattern in RegEx in js

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, dom

I want to edit a *pattern* that checks if text starts with **number/s** and ends with **number/s** or **operator** and return true or false based on test() method.

How can I do that with **JavaScript**?`

```
var str= "123+125",str2 = "123",str3 = "123*";
let RegularExpression = /^\d*(\d*|(\+|\-|\*|\/){1,})$/; //this pattern variable what I want to edit because it doesn't do what I want. 
let result1 = RegularExpression.test(str);
let result2 = RegularExpression.test(str);
let result2 = RegularExpression.test(str);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
It's not quite clear exactly what you want your regex to match, and how you're testing it, e.g. you're not using the `str2` and `str3` variables, and you're binding `result2` twice.
Perhaps consider viewing some documentation on regular expressions in JS, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

You could use repeat 1 or more times matching 1 or more digits, optionally followed by an operator.

```
^(?:\d+[+*/-]?)+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+[+*/-]?` Match 1+ digits optionally followed by either `+` `*` `/` `-`
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ezh3ec/1)

```js
let pattern = /^(?:\d+[+*/-]?)+$/m;
[
  "123+125",
  "",
  "123",
  "123*",
  "123+125-1"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern  `/^(\d*|[+/*-]?){1,}$/`

```js
var str= "123+125",str2 = "123",str3 = "123*";
let RegularExpression = /^(\d*|[+/*-]?){1,}$/; //this pattern variable what I want to edit because it doesn't do what I want. 
let result1 = RegularExpression.test(str);
let result2 = RegularExpression.test(str);
let result3 = RegularExpression.test(str);

console.log("res1:",result1,",res3:",result2,",res3:",result3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/^\d+([-+*\/]\d+)*[-+*\/]?$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lsQ0qX/1)

EXPLANATION:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-+*\/]                  any character of: '-', '+', '*', '\/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [-+*\/]?                 any character of: '-', '+', '*', '\/'
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

JavaScript:

```js
var str= "123+125",str2 = "123",str3 = "123*";
let RegularExpression = /^\d+([-+*\/]\d+)*[-+*\/]?$/;
console.log( RegularExpression.test(str) );
console.log( RegularExpression.test(str2) );
console.log( RegularExpression.test(str3) );
```